# Crear condición del IF en tiempo de ejecución, VB.NET 2010

Tags: vb.net

esta pregunta es para vb.net 2010. En una aplicación windows form.

Estoy intentando crear la condición del IF en tiempo de ejecución, es decir...tengo un TextBox donde el usuario puede poner una condición simple, digamos que "4>1". Para luego obtener este texto y ponerle en la condición del IF.

```
 Dim condicion As String = Me.PanelContenedor.Controls(aux).Controls("txt").Text
    If condicion Then
        **acciones**
    End If
```

En la primer linea lo que hago es obtener el texto del TextBox (el código es así porque este control fue creado en tiempo de ejecución).
Al intentar ponerlo en la condición del IF me tira el siguiente error (este error es en tiempo de ejecución).

> Conversion from string "4<1" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.

Creo que me da este error porque que al ponerle una sola variable debe ser si o si booleana. 
Hay alguna manera de poder pasar la condición entera y que la reconozca sin problemas?

Recuerden que la condición puede variar, y no siempre va a ser solo una consulta, pueden ser más de una, por ejemplo:  4>1 and 5>2 and .... etc

El usuario también podría usar variables (que ya están creadas en tiempo de diseño) para su condición ej:    `aux1<55`.

Me gustaría simplemente poder agarrar el texto y ponerlo en la condición if, pero supongo que no va a ser tan sencillo. 
Si alguno me puede ayudar un poco se lo agradecería.

Este código es para un Interprete que estoy creando, por si alguno tenia dudas de para que era.
Saludos!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200047/dynamic-code-execution-string-runtime-code-vb-net.. pero no se si en tu entorno va a funcionar...

Comment: Si te es permitido usar librerías, **NCalc** parece una buena opción para evaluar expresiones matemáticas [aquí está la librería](https://github.com/sheetsync/NCalc) y aquí hay un [ejemplo de uso en C# y vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23573485/8954823)

Comment: Puedes probar con la función eval: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/112781f0-1506-4c16-9088-6aacf26c943c/funcin-eval?forum=vbes